# Using a Function Defined In a Function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to use a function inside a function I already wrote, and it works with `list comprehension` and partial functions but not with `lambda` functions.

So my function is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from _functools import partial
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

arpdau = np.random.randint(0,100,15)

def fitARPDAU(arpdau, max_cohortday, method, par=None):

  valid = {'log', 'power', 'all'}
  if method not in valid:
      raise ValueError("results: method must be one of %r." % valid)

  values = par

  if method == 'log':

    if values == None:
      a = 1
      b = 0
      c = 1
      values = [a, b, c]
      bounds = [(1e-10, None), (1e-10, None), (None, None)]

    def getArpdauFunction(x, values):
      return values[0] * np.log(x + values[1]) + values[2]
  elif method == 'power':

    if values == None:
      a = 1
      b = 0
      c = .5
      d = 0
      values = [a, b, c, d]
      bounds = [(1e-10, None), (None, None), (1e-10, 1), (None, None)]


    def getArpdauFunction(x, values):
      return values[0] * (x + values[1]) ** values[2]+ values[3]

  elif method == 'all':

    log_loss = fitARPDAU(arpdau, max_cohortday, method='log', par=par)
    power_loss = fitARPDAU(arpdau, max_cohortday, method='power', par=par)

    combined_models = [log_loss, power_loss]
    losses = map(lambda x: x[0].fun, combined_models)
    return combined_models[np.argmin(losses)]

  def getLossOptim(values):

    # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    # arpdau_pred = [getArpdauFunction(x, values) for x in range(max_cohortday)]
    arpdau_pred_1 = map(lambda x: getArpdauFunction(x, values), range(max_cohortday))
    # arpdau_pred_2 = partial(getArpdauFunction, values=values)(range(271))
    return mean_squared_error(arpdau, arpdau_pred_1[:len(arpdau)])

  result = minimize(getLossOptim, values, method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bounds)

  return result, [getArpdauFunction(x, result.x) for x in range(max_cohortday)], result.x, method, getArpdauFunction

print fitARPDAU(arpdau, 100, method='all', par=None)
```

Is there any reason in getLossOptim that the partial and list comprehension work, but the lambda function doesn't?

The `lambda` function returns

```
NameError: global name 'getArpdauFunction' is not defined
```

Thanks!

---

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: There is nothing particular with the function being defined inside another function, the reason why you have this error is because the function may not be defined. For example,  if `method` is neither `'log'` nor `'power'`, then `getArpdauFunction` is undefined.

Comment: Indeed, what is getArpdauFunction() bound to if method = 'all' ?

Comment: Your posted code has no main program.  You haven't traced the code to show that `getArpdauFunction` is, indeed, defined during execution.

Comment: By the way, in python, power is the `**`. The `^` is XOR.

Comment: edited for completeness. I thought it would be enough to just get the theoretical explanation, but here's the complete code.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't an adequate problem specification

Comment: it returns the error NameError: global name 'getArpdauFunction' is not defined when I try to use the lambda definition versus the other two

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote and accept. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Comment: I don't think any have? I was only running it with 'log' as method before since I hadn't defined the all part yet.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote and accept. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with a function being defined inside of another function. If `method` is not `'log'` or `'power'`, then `getArpdauFunction()` is never defined.

You should probably define it for everything, then overload it if method is `'log'` or `'power'`.

This doesn't have to do with your problem, but you also shouldn't ever use `if x == None`. Because `None` is a singleton, it's more efficient and pythonic to use `if x is None`

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, your problem has nothing to do with a function being defined inside another function. The reason why you are getting an error is because the function is sometimes undefined; if `method` is neither `'log'` nor `'power'`, then `getArpdauFunction()` is never defined.

This is easy to fix. The cleanest method I can see for now is to declare several functions and then dynamically pick one:

```py
def identity(x): return x
def pp(x): return x+1
def mm(x): return x-1

functions = {
  "++": pp,
  "--": mm
}

default_function = identity

print(functions.get("++", default_function)(2)) # 3
print(functions.get("--", default_function)(2)) # 1
print(functions.get("non existing function name", default_function)(2)) # 2
```

If your functions are very short (as in this example, then you can directly write:

```py
functions = {
  "++": lambda x: x+1,
  "--": lambda x: x-1
}
```